# Getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined' in case of Encrypt in JavaScript and Decrypt in C# With AES Algorithm

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to encrypt the username & password in javascript with AES Algorithm,but getting error "Uncaught ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined  at SubmitsEncryp ((index):221) at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):119).
 i have use both Cdn downloaded file and use Cdn link but getting this error any idea how to remove this error:
Login .cshtml:

```
function SubmitsEncryp() {
                        //debugger;
                        var txtUserName = $("#Username").val();
                        var txtpassword = $("#Password").val();

                        if (txtUserName == "") {
                            alert('Please enter UserName');
                            return false;
                        }
                        else if (txtpassword == "") {
                            alert('Please enter Password');
                            return false;
                        }
                        else {
                            var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('8080808080808080');
                            var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('8080808080808080');

                            var encryptedlogin = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(txtUserName), key,

                            { keySize: 128 / 8, iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });

                            $("#HDUser").val(encryptedlogin);

                            var encryptedpassword = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(txtpassword), key,

                            { keySize: 128 / 8, iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 });

                            $("#HDpass").val(encryptedpassword);

                            alert('encrypted Username :' + encryptedlogin);
                            alert('encrypted password :' + encryptedpassword);
                        }
}
```

I have use CDN link and downloaded Cdn Link and use locally but in both case getting same error

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aes-js/3.1.2/index.min.js"></script> or
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/Scripts/aes.js"></script>
```

any idea on how to resolve it i have been stuck at this point ,Any idea would be appreciated

Comment: Just a note, you've left off the 't' in your function name. SubmitsEncryp should probably be SubmitsEncrypt

Comment: Try referencing the correct lib instead: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/aes.min.js`

Comment: @captiveCorsair no i have name it like that only "SubmitsEncryp"

Comment: @Mohan That's fine, and it won't affect anything. I just meant that it's a spelling mistake because Encryp is spelt Encrypt. Check my Answer for the possible solution to your issue :)

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen it is throwing error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lib' of undefined""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you've only included the aes.js library. Try using this CryptoJS library:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js
```